# Lumen: Is there any package to import CSV data to database?

Tags: php, mysql, lumen, import-csv

I have written following code to import CSV data in the database:

```
if(($request->file("csv") !== null)){
            $filename=$_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];
             if($_FILES["csv"]["size"] > 0)
             {
                $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                  while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                   {
                    DB::table('users')->updateOrInsert(
                        ['email' => $getData[1]],
                        ['name' => @$getData[0], 'phone' => @$getData[2], 'address'=> @$getData[3]]
                    );
                   }
                   fclose($file);
             }
          }
```

But it gives the following error when it reaches to insertion:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA5\xC7\x9EDO...' for column 'email' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `name`, `phone`, `address`) values (�ǞDO97*�~��ɸ8�O�c|n���E�

Why am I getting this error? Is there any Lumen package to import CSV to database which has proper documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You have an encoding problem. Your table's encoding (collation) does not allow some UTF characters to be inserted. You will need to alter your table and change its collation to [utf8mb4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html).